# Aggregating small values in a frequency bar plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series of sorted percentage values like this :

```
A -> 0.001
B -> 0.0012
C -> 0.0015
...
H -> 0.02
I -> 0.03
J -> 0.041
...
X -> 0.12
Y -> 0.31
Z -> 0.4
```

(I typed those by hand, I am not familiar with how to type those python outputs in DSSE, sorry! If anyone has a hint on that, it would be nice. If this pandas series would be named "content_distribution", content_distribution.X would return the float 0.12 .)

I want to obtain a Series which looks like this :

```
Other -> 0.07
I -> 0.03
J -> 0.041
...
X -> 0.12
Y -> 0.31
Z -> 0.4
```

because those small values are irrelevant to display in a plot that I want to make, and I want to keep the big values on display. Is there any pandas-ic or pythonic way to do that? I can write my own script, but anything I try out looks non-pandas-ic (even though it sort of works).

(I also don't know if "aggregating" is the correct pandas term for this, if anyone has a better one, he or she is welcome to edit my title.)

Comment: It isn't completely clear to me which values should be placed into *Other*. Are all rows with percentages below a certain threshold summed up and a row called *Other* is set equal to that value?

Comment: Sort, and then do a thresholding. Should be straightforward. No "clustering" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where I create a new row called **Other**, which contains the sum of all values below a given `threshold`.

I then remove the rows that were below that threshold (and so included in the sum), so the final Pandas Series only has values above the `threshold`, plus the new **Other** row.

This is all performed on a randomly generated Pandas Series, as follows:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np

In [2]: X = pd.Series(np.random.random(20))

In [3]: X
Out[3]: 
0     0.507151
1     0.366259
2     0.444196
3     0.027280    this will be in the sum
4     0.132785    this will be in the sum
5     0.993170
6     0.614712
7     0.942894
8     0.516255
9     0.107436
10    0.710416
11    0.512221
12    0.502685
13    0.753515
14    0.894735
15    0.780213
16    0.998315
17    0.971558
18    0.504525
19    0.224767
dtype: float64

In [4]: threshold = 0.2

In [5]: X.loc['Other'] = X[X < threshold].sum()

In [6]: X.drop(X[X < threshold].index, inplace=True)

In [7]: X
Out[7]: 
0        0.507151
1        0.366259
2        0.444196
5        0.993170
6        0.614712
7        0.942894
8        0.516255
10       0.710416
11       0.512221
12       0.502685
13       0.753515
14       0.894735
15       0.780213
16       0.998315
17       0.971558
18       0.504525
19       0.224767
Other    0.267501
dtype: float64
```

Notice that the indices still match the original values, i.e. they are not continguously numbered - indeices `3` and `4` have been *dropped*/removed.
If you want to get continuously numbered indices back, you can do the following:

```
X.reset_index()
```

This creates a new index and puts the original one shown above in a new column called `index`, which can then itself be dropped if desired:

```
X.drop('index', axis=1)
```

That will remove the label **Other**, which was in the original index.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but it's good to see that someone agrees. Thanks!